# Is there way to run PHP in Visual Studio code, without debug config

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

There are way to configure Visual Studio Code for debug, but need only to run PHP code.. and unnecessary for configure xDebug.

Is there way to run PHP from box ?

Comment: Do you mean running some PHP command-line script, and not something else like e.g. developing PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but I believe that VSCode lacks the ability to run arbitrary commands out of the box. However, there's a third-party extension called [Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattn.Runner) that implements this feature. It comes pre-configured for several script types, including PHP, so you just need to open the script and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

If you need something more specific, such as configuring a list of named tasks, there're other extensions that do so.